# Group records from Datatable by Linq and add them to a Dictionary

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a datatable which is filled from sql query. Sample Query:

```
A B C D E
1 1 x y z
1 1 x y z
1 2 x y z
2 1 x y z
```

i want to group them like this one: (A and B will be unique)

```
A B C D E
1 1 x y z
1 1 x y z

A B C D E
1 2 x y z

A B C D E
2 1 x y z
```

i tried with linq but could not properly done it. i checked similar questions but they did not solve my problem. It does not have to be linq but i thought if i use linq and group them by using Dictionary that would be good solution for me.

Comment: add more details about expected output

Comment: i just want to group them using 2 column as unique then add them to dictionary where key is a combination of this 2 column and vale is all columns.

Comment: A B C D E ? is it output or column name ?

Comment: they are column name and 1 1 x y z is the first row. i could not manage to do it with linq then i decided to try it with foreach and dictionary.